# C# Event Handler is null after subscribing

Tags: c#, maui

I have this "background service" class

```
public interface IBackgroundService
{
    event EventHandler<string> DataReceived;
    void Start();
    void Stop();
}

public partial class BackgroundService: IBackgroundService
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public event EventHandler<string> DataReceived;
    public void OnDataReceived(string data)
    {
        DataReceived?.Invoke(this, data);
    }

    private static BackgroundService instance;
    public static BackgroundService Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new BackgroundService();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    private void ReportProgress(string progress)
    {
        OnDataReceived("data=" + progress);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        StartService();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        StopService();
    }
}
```

OnDataReceived is being called but the event handler DataReceived is null.

The calling code is a ViewModel is a .NET MAUI project and is doing this:

```
_service = BackgroundService.Instance;
_service.DataReceived += (sender, data) => { Message = data; };
```

And the DI container is:

`builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBackgroundService>(BackgroundService.Instance);`

I probably don't need this tbh but I was using DI rather than the `Instance¬ thing above and neither approach worked.

The issue is DataReceived is null and so its not invoked.
Any clues?

I also tried adding a second class in-between the caller and my service and that seemed to work.
This second class had a similar setup with an event handler and an OnDataReceived method etc.

DataReceived should not be null because the event handler is subscribed to with `_service.DataReceived += (sender, data) => { Message = data; };`

Android specific implementation of the service:

```
[Service]
public partial class BackgroundService : Service
{
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    //Start and Stop Intents, set the actions for the MainActivity to get the state of the foreground service
    //Setting one action to start and one action to stop the foreground service
    public void StartService()
    {
        Intent startService = new Intent(MainActivity.ActivityCurrent, typeof(BackgroundService));
        startService.SetAction("START_SERVICE");
        MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.StartService(startService);
    }

    public void StopService()
    {
        Intent stopIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.ActivityCurrent, this.Class);
        stopIntent.SetAction("STOP_SERVICE");
        MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.StartService(stopIntent);
    }

    [return: GeneratedEnum]//we catch the actions intents to know the state of the foreground service
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        if (intent.Action == "START_SERVICE")
        {
            Notification notification = BuildNotification();

            StartForeground(100, notification);

            DoStuff();

        }
        else if (intent.Action == "STOP_SERVICE")
        {
            StopForeground(true);//Stop the service
            StopSelfResult(startId);
        }

        return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
    }

    private async Task DoStuff()
    {
        var cancellationtoken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var c = 0;

            // Long-running task logic
            while (!cancellationtoken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // Simulate some work
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                c++;
                if (c > 50)
                {
                    c = 0;
                    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                }


                // Report progress (optional)
                double progress = (c + 1) * 10;
                OnDataReceived("Android " + progress);
            }

        }, cancellationtoken);
    }

    private Notification BuildNotification()
    {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("ServiceChannel", "ServiceDemo", NotificationImportance.Max);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
        manager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this, "ServiceChannel")
           .SetContentTitle("Service Working")
           .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.quix_icon_light)
           .SetOngoing(true)
           .Build();
        return notification;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: `CancellationTokenSource` is `IDisposable` but you aren't disposing of your `cancellationTokenSource`.

Comment: Have you tried DI with `builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBackgroundService, BackgroundService>();` ? And then registering the event on the injected instance?

Comment: **Where** is `_service.DataReceived += (sender, data) => { Message = data; };` being executed? Have you used your debugger? I suggest you make your class a true singleton by making its ctor `private` and use an eagerly-evaluated (not lazily-evaluated) `readonly static` field to hold the singleton reference - and monitor ctor invocations by using a `static int _instanceCount` with `Interlocked.Increment( ref _instanceCount )` in the private ctor, just to be sure.

Comment: @dai that's being executed in a ViewModel constructor. The debugger shows `DataReceived?.Invoke(this, data)` being called and DataReceived being null.

Comment: Not sure if i can post this.. but a short loom showing the issue https://www.loom.com/share/65ca27eeb6af485592c78853035e004f

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods - yep doing this instead of using the instance way also have the same issue `builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBackgroundService, BackgroundService>();` (and I also put the interface in the ViewModels constructor and I get a BackgroundServiced resolved)

Comment: @Dai apparently I have to have a public ctor maybe because I'm using partial classes to handle the different platforms my MAUI app is targeting (and to implement the platform specific stuff - of which I have none at the moment.) - I will try to remove the platform specificity and have it all in one class for now. Perhaps something odd is going on there.

Comment: Alternatively, can you reproduce it in a Linqpad program? or on DotNetFiddle?

Comment: What's in the other `partial` definition of `BackgroundService`? (Also, I really recommend you rename the class and the interface, just to disambiguate it from .NET's own `IBackgroundService` - perhaps use `interface IStevesBackgroundService` and `class ActualStevesBackgroundService` just for now?

Comment: partial class namespaces. Verify that your platform-specific partial-class files use the cross-platform namespace. If you have a `namespace myproject.android { partial class myclass`, that won't be the same class, because it is a different namespace.

Comment: Renamed to MyBackgroundService and the interface as well. No change.
I will create a fiddle and see if i can reproduce there. Will also try and create a new class that's not partial to see if it has the same issues.

Comment: While debugging and stopped on the `Start()` method. I noticed that `DataReceived` was not null. But then when `OnDataReceived` was called it was null. I tried a console .writeline to print `CurrentManagedThreadId`. Both threads were id `1`. Finally, I tried making the event handler static. That worked. I guess the issue is a difference between the threads in play here. Despite the report that theyre on CurrentManagedThreadId 1.

Comment: Added Android implementation. Note the `DoStuff` method starting a new task. Is this causing my issues?